# ipython looks into a virtualenv of a different python verion for some reason

Tags: ipython

so i had ipython and it worked fine for a while. Then I used buildout to install ipdb.
The case is: ipython and python2.7 systemwide
naked-python virtualenvs in the home folder.
A plone instance in the home folder using virtualenv of python2.4 from the naked-python i mentioned

now i try to run ipython and i get

```
fakedrake@fakedrake-arch ~ $ ipython
/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/pprint.py:39: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module cStringIO: This Python has API version 1013, module cStringIO has versi
on 1012.                                                                                                                                                                                    
  from cStringIO import StringIO as _StringIO
/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/string.py:528: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module strop: This Python has API version 1013, module strop has version 1012
.                                                                                                                                                                                           
  from strop import maketrans, lowercase, uppercase, whitespace
/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/unittest.py:51: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module time: This Python has API version 1013, module time has version 1012.
  import time
/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/heapq.py:132: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module itertools: This Python has API version 1013, module itertools has versi
on 1012.                                                                                                                                                                                    
  from itertools import islice, repeat
/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/bisect.py:82: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _bisect: This Python has API version 1013, module _bisect has version 1
012.                                                                                                                                                                                        
  from _bisect import bisect_right, bisect_left, insort_left, insort_right, insort, bisect
/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/heapq.py:306: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _heapq: This Python has API version 1013, module _heapq has version 101
2.                                                                                                                                                                                          
  from _heapq import heappush, heappop, heapify, heapreplace, nlargest, nsmallest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 26, in <module>
    import IPython.Shell
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    __import__(name,glob,loc,[])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/ipstruct.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.genutils import list2dict2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/genutils.py", line 20, in <module>
    import doctest
  File "/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/doctest.py", line 99, in <module>
    import unittest, difflib, pdb, tempfile
  File "/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/tempfile.py", line 33, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/random.py", line 41, in <module>
    from warnings import warn as _warn
  File "/home/fakedrake/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.4/warnings.py", line 258, in <module>
    simplefilter("ignore", category=OverflowWarning, append=1)
NameError: name 'OverflowWarning' is not defined
```

If you require any further info regarding the problem just tell me, i dont know wht else might be relevant...
(i run arch-linux)

Comment: You might want to check your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have both python2.4 and python 2.7 libraries?? When ipython (v2.7) is importing doctest, it's moving into a python2.4 library. I'd inspect your PYTHONPATH environment variable, as well as sys.path i.e.

```
import sys, os
print '\n'.join( [p for p in sys.path ] )
print '\n'.join( [[ for
```

The order of this is important. Figure out why doctest is being imported from that python2.4 directory, and then remove that directory from sys.path. According to [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2006-May/033573.html), OverflowWarning is removed upon the upgrade to python2.5